# Parsing date strings: some correctly formatted strings return errors

Tags: java, scala

While trying to retrieve day of the week from the string, sometimes an error occurs although the string corresponds to the predefined format.

Below is the function that is used to parse strings and format definition:

```
val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
def getDayOfWeek(date: String): Int = {
    val stringToParse = date.substring(0, 19)
    try {
      val now = Calendar.getInstance()
      now.setTime(dateFormat.parse(stringToParse))
      println("Correct time string: " + stringToParse)
      now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => println("Wrong time string: " + stringToParse)
        -1
    } 
}
```

Below are the examples of successfully/unsuccessfully parsed strings:

```
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Wrong time string: 2017-05-04 15:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-06-13 07:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 15:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 04:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 15:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-06-13 07:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 15:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-06-13 07:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-06-13 07:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Wrong time string: 2017-06-13 07:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-01-01 05:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
Correct time string: 2017-05-04 16:00:00
```

Does anyone know what could cause the error in the above cases? I don't spot any differences between the successful/unsuccessful examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps printing the error message of the exception may help you identify the error more specifically.

Comment: I can only support @stefanobaghino as you are correctly parsing "2017-06-13 07:00:00" as well as wrongly.

Comment: One further word of advice: catching `Throwable` is generally not advisable. You may want to look into the `NonFatal` extractor, documented here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.control.NonFatal$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is your SimpleDateFormat is declared globally.

Bring your line

```
val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

inside the function.

SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, and I assume you must be calling getDayoftheweek() function from outside non-synchronized code.